# using model method to instantiate object in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two classes defined like so in my models.py file:

```
class Branch_Circle(models.Model):
    ...
    trunk_circle = models.ForeignKey('Trunk_Circle', null=True)

class Trunk_Circle(models.Model):
    ...
    def create_branch_circle(self):
        branch_circle = Branch_Circle(trunk_circle=self)
        branch_circle.save()
        return branch_circle
```

Using shell I instantiate a Trunk_Circle object first, then call its 'create_branch_circle' method and expect it to create a Branch_Circle object.  It doesn't:

```
import Trunk_Circle
import Branch_Circle

r = Trunk_Circle
s = r.create_branch_circle
```

When I call `Branch_Circle.objects.all()` it is empty.  Also, the type of 's' is `<bound method Trunk_Circle.create_branch_circle of <Trunk_Circle: Trunk_Circle object>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To instantiate an object or call a method you have to use **brackets** `()`:

```
r = Trunk_Circle()
s = r.create_branch_circle()
```